# run jaxb1 code on jdk1.6

Tags: java, jaxb, java-6

I have old jaxb1 code that I am trying to run on JDK1.6(u 31).
It compiled fine. When I try to run I get the error -

> Error constructing QTIResultsProcessingV12:Input is not a well formed document: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 not found

So I tried to google and found that I have to place `jaxb1_impl.jar` in classpath. 
I did not find this jar in jdk lib , so I downloaded JAXB RI 2.1.10 and put the `jaxb1_impl.jar` in classpath. Yet I get the same error.

Migrating jaxb1->jaxb2 is something not desired at this point as this is a short term solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work fine. Show us the code that produced that error message.

Comment: @skaffman - It was a wrong classpath to jaxb1-impl.jar. So I have proceeded. It now fails when running unit tests while unmarshalling.  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( QTI_RESULTS_SCHEMA_PACKAGE );
      Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
      u.setValidating(false);
      Object obj = u.unmarshal(instream);
      if(obj instanceof QtiResultReport) {

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete comment. 
      if(obj instanceof QtiResultReport) {  all code here } else { throw new JAXBException (....); } The JAXBException gets thrown so it cannot find the root of the document. can you suggest? I have changed nothing in the xml.

Comment: Adding to my question above. QtiResultReport is an interface.